# Excel to SQL table field value appending with 0

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, ssis-2012

I loaded an Excel file into an SQL table. The Excel file, one field consists of `VARCHAR` data (of data type general). When loaded into an SQL table, some of these values are prefixed with zero.

Example: in the Excel file it is `1081999` the same value become `01081999` in the SQL table.

What might be the reason for this ?

Comment: If you do a CSV extraction of your Excel file (so you have the raw values), what is the number ? `1081999` or `01081999` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel will hide leading 0's as it identifies the fields content as a number and displays it as such. I would assume that the excel worksheet does indeed contain these leading 0's and they are simply not shown by Excel. If you change the type of the column from General to Text do they show up??

As a side note, if these are indeed numbers you should be storing them in a numeric datatype in the database...

Comment: These are csv file ,but always opens in excel! Just wondering how to make it permanently open in notepad++

Comment: In the right click menu for Open With.. if you chose 'another program', you will get a window which will allow you to select NotePad++ and a tickbox at the bottom saying 'Always use this app to open csv files'